# Joomla Prev and Next images not loading on diffrent languages

Tags: jquery, html, css, joomla

I got a Owl Carousel on my website, but the owl-prev and owl-next only work on the default website. On the other websites with for example /en in the link the Images dont load.

I work with Modules.
Here is the Script for the carousel:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $('.home-carousel').owlCarousel({
                stagePadding: 0,
                margin: 0,
                loop: true,
                nav: true,
                navText: ["<img src='images/navigation-links.png'>",
                "<img src='images/navigation-rechts.png'>"],
                dots: false,
                autoPlay: 5000,
                responsiveRefreshRate: 1,
                responsiveClass: true,
                responsive:{
                    // breakpoint from 0 up
                    0 :{
                        items: 1,
                    },
                    // breakpoint from 738 up
                    738 :{
                        items: 3,
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

And here the CSS for the prev and next:

```
.owl-prev, .owl-next {
position : absolute;
opacity : 0.5;
transition : opacity 0.25s ease-in-out;
top : 50%;
margin-top : -35px;
}
.owl-prev > img, .owl-next > img {
width : 70px;
height : 70px;
}
.owl-prev:hover {
opacity : 0.9;
}
.owl-next:hover {
opacity : 0.9;
}
.owl-prev {
left : 0;
content : url(images/navigation-links.png);
}
.owl-next {
right : 0;
content : url(images/navigation-rechts.png);
}
```

I got the content: url as a fix that allready worked while I was workig on my Laptop.

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put full source of image.

```
navText: ["<img src='http://www.YourSite/images/navigation-links.png'>",
```